# Custom Plugin Suddenly Giving 404 on All Pages and Not Showing Published Pages/Posts on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, http-status-code-404, custom-post-type

I created a plugin to add a custom post type to a wordpress site. Everything was functioning perfectly fine together. I was trying to add in a new function to allow revisions to appear with the custom fields.

Suddenly, I'm getting a 404 message on every single page and when on the admin panel, I can't view any posted pages, posts, or custom posts. It says they are published but I can't see them (yes I am a full admin).

I deactivated my plugin and everything came back.

I deleted it and reverted it to an older version but am still encountering this problem. The version of the plugin currently installed was working just fine yesterday. I have changed nothing else on the site either. I have tried to update permalinks and repair the databases.

I'm not sure what code to even share here. Does anyone have any ideas? I can't find anything when searching.

Comment: Did you try manually reset .htacess?

Comment: Yup. Did not work.

Comment: I installed a plugin called WP reset to show me what changes between having the plugin active or not active. It is telling me "site_transient_update_plugins" and several other things relating to "transient"

Comment: Oh, this is a disaster. Another weapon >> Manual update of wp installation.

Comment: I ended up deleting wordpress and installing it fresh again. It's working so far. No idea what was causing the problem in the end.

Comment: Any of your plugin infected core files.